# Python and pop3 to parse emails

Tags: python, email, pop3

Looked through people's past attempts to do similar things. The code I have found as a basis is

```
import poplib
from email import parser

pop_conn = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop.gmail.com')
pop_conn.user('---------')
pop_conn.pass_('--------')
#Get messages from server:
messages = [pop_conn.retr(i) for i in range(1, len(pop_conn.list()[1]) + 1)]
# Concat message pieces:
messages = ['\n'.join(mssg[1]) for mssg in messages]
#Parse message intom an email object:
messages = [parser.Parser().parsestr(mssg) for mssg in messages]
for message in messages:
    print(message['subject'])
    print(message['body'])
pop_conn.quit()
```

I keep getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "E:\False Apparition\Desktop\test.py", line 10, in <module>
        messages = ['\n'.join(''.join(mssg[1]) for mssg in messages)]
    File "E:\False Apparition\Desktop\test.py", line 10, in <genexpr>
        messages = ['\n'.join(''.join(mssg[1]) for mssg in messages)]
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found
```

Is this because I am using python 3.6 instead of an earlier version? Essentially I want to be able to quickly parse a server status email to deliver the important stats, but only emails that have a specific subject line (as I could get other emails). I'm familiar with parsing but without being able to get a subject or the body I'm a bit stuck.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to decode the bytes to string. `['\n'.join(mssg[1].decode()) for mssg in messages]`. The decode function also takes an encoding as a string, if you already know what kind of data the bytes contains.

Comment: Now it has another error -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\False Apparition\Desktop\test.py", line 10, in <module>
    messages = ['\n'.join(mssg[1].decode()) for mssg in messages]
  File "E:\False Apparition\Desktop\test.py", line 10, in <listcomp>
    messages = ['\n'.join(mssg[1].decode()) for mssg in messages]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'decode'... The email I'm trying to parse is a dump of status information from a server constining things like SMART and Scrub data... There are alot of lines of output but each line is fairly short (~50 char maybe?)

Comment: I suppose that means mssg[1] is a list, but how it ends up being a list I have no idea... Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: Ah, my bad. `'\n'.join(map(bytes.decode, mssg[1]))` should work. `str.join` takes an `iterable` as an argument. Not sure what I was thinking yesterday. :)

Comment: Thanks that works. I ended up trying out imap and it worked out better for what I intended than pop3. But thanks; I'll know this for future when I use pop3 again.